# dynamic thumbnail with php

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

I want to dynamically generate thumbnails, and I found from one of posts here a recommendation that uses [SimpleImage](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) class, it is usage like this:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
include('SimpleImage.php');
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load('picture.jpg');
$image->resizeToWidth(150);
$image->output();
```

and the output method is as following:

```
function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

    if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
       imagejpeg($this->image);

    } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {
       imagegif($this->image);

    } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
       imagepng($this->image);

    }
}
```

this works fine with outputing images, because I received something like binary code on client side. but what I want is a thumbnail slider, so I need all image to be in a <ul></ul>, I tried this using ajax:

**updated**

```
function thumb($files){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($files as $file){
        $thumb = new Thumbnail();
        $thumb->load($file->getFilePath());
        $thumb->resizeToWidth(80);
        echo '<li>'.$thumb->output().'</li>';
    };
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

but this does not seem to work. how can I get output something like this so I can do a slider gallery.

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="path here"></li>
  <li><img src="path here"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What you need to do is wrap all the image generation code into a script that just serves one single image.  Then your HTML calls that script in the `<img src>`.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625427/how-to-serve-multiple-images-which-reside-above-the-www-root-within-a-single-page/6625590#6625590

Comment: This is because you cannot output multiple images with one `Content-type: image/jpeg` header.

Comment: @Kthompson,,,means I dont get the image list..only binary like code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing two things: html layout of images and the scaling of images.  You need to keep your scaling code - which is perfectly fine - in a separate php file, say, scale.php - like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    include('SimpleImage.php');
    $image = new SimpleImage();
    $image->load($_GET['image']);
    $image->resizeToWidth(150);
    $image->output();
?>
```

And in your main php, you'll have a code like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($files as $file){
        echo '<li><img src="scale.php?image=' . $file . '"/></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: It is not good idea to use directly image name from GET parameter. Try using mysql table for example with data like "image_id => file_name.jpg" and than pass numeric image_id to your script.

Comment: hi, thanks for you answer, should I save the generated thumnail somewhere?

Comment: @Ostin,i kind of not understand you. if we use numeric id, where do we get the file path?

Comment: @bingjie2680 it can be mysql or other data source of your choice. If you can't do this, you have to check carefully every parameter passed to your script in GET.

Comment: Saving thumbnails to separate place can protect you from later problems of high server load.

Comment: @Ostin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1370/discussion-between-bingjie2680-and-ostin)